# Additional info at file upload with playframework

Tags: java, http, file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can i pass additional info in my file uploading request:

My action looks like this:

```
public static Result upload() {
    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");
...
```

and this is my view:

```
@form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
        <input type="file" name="picture">
        <p>
            <input type="submit">
        </p>
    }
```

As far as i understand it would be no prblem to add another image to the request,
but i want to add some other information (the id of the item which the uploaded picture belongs to, otherwise its worthless...) to the request.

Tried it with a hidden input field, but could not retrieve the value in my action.

Thanks for any proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
List<FilePart> files = body.getFiles();
// store files etc.
Map<String, String[]> asFormUrlEncoded = request().body().asMultipartFormData().asFormUrlEncoded();
String[] descriptionParams  = asFormUrlEncoded.get("description");
// save descriptions
```

Comment: I'm not able to try this right now but if it works for it should work for me too. Thanks a lot!